# javascript object method definition difference

Tags: javascript, object, syntax, constructor, difference

I'm trying to find my way into learning Javascript and am running into an issue where several pieces of code that I'm told were identical, have different outcomes. I have found there are three ways of defining an object (instance):

version 1:

```
var obj = { //create the instance
  variable: value
};
obj.fun = function() {
  obj.variable += 1;
  console.log('obj.fun is called');
};
```

version 2:

```
var obj = { //create the instance
  variable: value,
  fun: function() {
    this.variable += 1;
    console.log('obj.fun is called');
  }
};
```

version 3:

```
function Obj() { //create the class
  this.variable = value;
  this.fun = function() {
    this.variable += 1;
    console.log('obj.fun is called');
  }
};
obj = new Obj(); //create the instance
```

In fact what I am trying to do is creating a mouse event handler in a HTML5 canvas using this:

```
canvas_id.addEventListener("mousedown", obj.fun, false);
```

Currently, only version 1 is working if I try to call the function `obj.fun` using this event listener, but I prefer to use version 2 because I think it's cleaner. In versions 2 and 3, the function is executed when calling `obj.fun(newvalue)` (the console message is created), but the variable isn't changed to the new value; if I try to retrieve `obj.variable` the original value is returned.

I'd like to know what's the exact difference between these three versions of writing, so I can understand what to use when. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

What you have in the first version is a named variable `obj` keeping the desired object. In the two other ones, `this` (the context of the call) isn't your object (a common problem with event handling callbacks).

You can still use those versions by changing the binding to

```
canvas_id.addEventListener("mousedown", obj.fun.bind(obj), false);
```

or (to be compatible with IE8)

```
canvas_id.addEventListener("mousedown", function(){ obj.fun() }, false);
```

Comment: @Shaded Technically it's more a problem of function execution context here.

Comment: Yup, you just took javascript to a new level for me... Now I'm off to learn the difference between context and scope!

Comment: Thanks dystroy :) It seems I misundestand the `this` keyword. After reading your answer and doing some searches I found [an explanation on `this`](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html) that helps understanding the issue. However, as I want to put the object in an external library I want to keep the call as simple as possible. But thanks for the alternatives, I didn't know about them. I used version 2 and changed `this` to `obj` everywhere and it worked. Thanks for the explanation!